# Suppose the function $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ has left and right derivatives at $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, continuity

I have been trying to solve the following problem:

Suppose the function $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ has left and right derivatives at $0$.Then at $x=0$, which of the following options is correct?

> (a)$f$ must be continuous but may not be differentiable,
>   (b)$f$ need not be continuous but must be left continuous  or right continuous,
>   (c)$f$ must be differentiable,
>   (d)if $f$ is continuous then $f$ must be differentiable.

Could someone point me in the right direction.Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2):

The function $f(x)=|x|$ should guide you towards the right answer. Also, if $f(x)$ is left-differentiable, what can you say about the left limit?

Comment: Sir,since $f$ is left-differentiable,it should be left-continuous.here the left limit for the function is $0$.

Comment: And since it is right differentiable, it is also right continuous ;) What can you say about a function which is both left and right continuous?

Comment: @N.S. is there no issue due to the fact that we dont know the left derivative is equal to the right derivative?

Comment: @MSEoris Nope. $\lim_{x \to x_o^+} f(x)-f(x_0)=\lim_{x \to x_o^+} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}(x-x_0)=f'^{+}(x_0) \cdot 0=0$... In the computation it is irrelevant what the left/right derivatives are, since they are multiplied by $0$.

Comment: I think the function is continuous as for the function being both left and right continuous and its value being equal to $0$.

Comment: You cannot say anything about the value ;) If $f(x)$ has the given properties then so has $f(x)+C$ where $c$ is a constant ;)

Comment: Then i think option $(b)$ is the right choice.